# Restrict access to GCS bucket but keep up Cloud CDN accessible to everyone

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-cdn

I'm new to Google Cloud and recently I've set up the bucket as the origin for cloud CDN. All is fine but I have a question. Can you and if so how private access to the bucket, so the only way to get the data is through cloud cdn IP not through storage.googleapis.com/bucketname/filename

Comment: Review Cloud CDN [authorization](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/authenticate-content). This [method](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/using-signed-cookies#configure_permissions) is probably what you want. However, if you are making the data public, why do you care if they access the bucket directly? An object downloaded from Cloud Storage is cheaper than one from Cloud CDN. If you are trying to restrict access to authorized users, then use [Signed URLs](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/using-signed-urls). Edit your post with details so that a correct answer can be created.

Comment: I was just curious because for me personally blocking cloud storage when using cloud CDN makes more sense than having them both accessible on the client side. Nevertheless I've check out the pricing and yeah it's cheaper to use GCS with cache rather than GCS + CDN if there is not that much data

Comment: I am not saying do not use Cloud CDN. I am asking why impose authorization, management tasks, and introduce potential issues if there is no real benefit to you or your users? If the data is public, enable Cloud CDN, and do not worry if a user can bypass the CDN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Mr @JohnHanley mentioned. Posting this information as an answer for other users to understand this concern.

Basically what you based on what Mr Hanley mentioned is [Cloud Storage permission](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/using-signed-cookies#configure_permissions) and for strict access and for authorized user you can use [signed url](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/using-signed-urls)